# Как извлечь число?

Tags: java

На вход программе поступают данные,формат которых приведен ниже. Эти данные записаны через пробел, причём ровно один между каждой парой (то есть всего по три пробела в каждой строке).

<Фамилия> — строка, состоящая не более чем из 30 символов без пробелов

<Имя> — строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов без пробелов

<Число 1> — целое число в диапазоне от 1 до 99

<Число 2> — целое число в диапазоне от 1 до 100

Мне нужно,чтобы из этой последовательности извлекалось число <Число 2>.У меня такой код,но нужно,чтобы все было записано в одной строке

```
surname = scanner.nextLine();
name = scanner.nextLine();
ch1 = scanner.nextInt();
ch2 = scanner.nextInt();
```

Пример входной строки:

Ivanov Ivan 50 87

Пример выходных данных:

87

Comment: непонятно, что у вас не работает. поясните

Comment: @michael_best мне нужно как-то извлечь число 87 из строки и вывести в печать

Answer (score 6):

По поводу сканнера, код которого вы приводите:

Вы вызываете метод`Scanner.nextLine()`, этот вызов возвращает строку до перевода каретки, для получения символов до пробела Вам нужен метод `Scanner.next()`

[Вот тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) все достаточно информативно

---

Однако сканнер вам тут вряд ли нужен, для получения необходимого элемента исходную строку можно разбить по пробелам методом `split`, и к полученному массиву строк, обратиться по индексу, это вернет вам строку.

```
String element = arg.split(" ")[3];
```

Comment: нехорошо чужие ответы воровать!

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Ваш ответ даже на ответ непохож, что там воровать-то? Строчка кода и никаких объяснений.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець 1. Вам репутации нехватает? Я потрудился почитал Ваши ответы, оценил достойные.  2. Вы считаете что застолбили ответ написав одну строчку кода? Потрудитесь написать более развернутый ответ, то что вы написали это комментарий.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Мои ответы помогают людям. Как пользоваться репутацией даже не знаю... И не знал что ответ можно "застолбить". С какой целью, если не секрет, так делаете?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець тогда мне категорически не ясен Ваш комментарий по поводу того что Я украл чужой ответ.

Comment: И, насколько я знаю, автор вопроса решает какой ответ принять - краткий как выстрел или развернутый.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець так хначит я зря голосовал за Ваши ответы недавно и я могу убрать голоса обоатно?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я не говорил (и даже не писАл), что вы украли мой ответ (см. еще раз мои сообщения - они не редактировались). Было написано, что так делать НЕХОРОШО! Сразу после моего ответа вы отредактировали свой ответ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ зря или нет - решать вам, т.к. вы были инициатором ваших действий, а не я. Я реально не знаю зачем нужны все эти голоса %)

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Вы не понимаете суть stackoverflow, тут не за галочками охота происходит а написание качественных ответов на вопросы

Comment: ребята, успокойтесь. могу вам обоим полайкать, чтобы никто не обижался

Comment: @Stranger качественные ответы тут мало кто понимает :) а вот количество не качественного текста сразу видно.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець отвечая на вопрос автора без объяснений, вы помогаете только ему и тем у кого точно такая же проблема, отвечая с объяснениями вы затрагиваете более широкий круг людей, что есть хорошо. (сам я на мастер ответов :) )

Answer (score 0):

Если ваша строка `line`, `int number2 = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[3]);`

Answer (score 0):

Если только последнее число надо извлечь, то можно так:

```
scanner.nextLine().split(" ")[3]
```